# MySQL count doesn't return null counts with the rest of my data.

Tags: mysql, count, null

Issue: I cannot get my database to return 0/NULL for location_id's that exist in the database but do not have any items assigned to them in tbl_inventory.. in ADDITION to the counts of the location_id's that DO have items assigned to them.

**tbl_inventory: (only posting pertainent columns)**

```
location_id, shop_id, ...
1          | 100
1          | 100
3          | 106
4          | 100
10         | 102
2          | 100
```

**tbl_location: (posting ALL columns)**

```
location_id, location_desc, shop_id
1          | Shop Stock   | 100
2          | Crash Kit    | 100
3          | Site 4       | 106
4          | Radar Site   | 102
5          | New Location | 100
...
10         | Fire Stn 2   | 100
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
tbl_location.location_desc, 
tbl_inventory.location_id, 
COALESCE(COUNT(tbl_location.location_id), 0) as 'idCnt'
FROM tbl_location 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_inventory
ON tbl_location.location_id = tbl_inventory.location_id
WHERE tbl_inventory.shop_id = 110
GROUP BY tbl_location.location_id;
```

**Results**

```
location_desc, location_id, idCnt
Shop Stock   | 1          | 2
Crash Kit    | 2          | 1
Fire stn 2   | 10         | 1
```

**What is missing** here is location_id 5 from tbl_location

```
New Location | 5          | 0 (or Null, because there are none in tbl_inventory)
```

**Explanation:**

my tbl_location is a table of container labels assigned (and created) by individual shops in our network. The shop then has ownership over that container and can assign parts to it (tbl_inventory.location_id) for inventory purposes..

My PHP application uses this query to produce a list of available locations and grants options based on the amount of items assigned to it.. If the ammount of items is 0 I would like to be able to delete the location.

**Even Worse**

If I were to remove the GROUP BY the whole query gets mucked up.. 
Only returning 1 location_id/desc and summing the entire total up on that row.

```
location_desc, location_id, idCnt
Shop Stock   | 1          | 5
```

I'm not sure what is actually going on here (in the even worse block) - however I've manually counted and the original query returns the correct counts I just can't get it to portray Locations that **DO**, in fact, exist in the database but do NOT, in fact, have any items assigned to them.

Anyone have any insight? All the fixes I've found have yet to work.

Answer (score 2):

Move

```
WHERE tbl_inventory.shop_id = 110
```

condition to the join condition

```
 ON tbl_location.location_id = tbl_inventory.location_id
AND tbl_inventory.shop_id = 110
```

After your `FROM` and `LEFT JOIN` clauses have worked - there is a row with `0` there, but `WHERE` filters it out, since there is no `tbl_inventory.shop_id = 110` in that row

PS: in select it should be `tbl_location.location_id`, not `tbl_inventory.location_id`